# Expect script hanging

Tags: linux, password, manjaro, expect

I'm trying to use expect to automate my login process in ovpn but due to some mistake it is not going well. My script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout -1

spawn openvpn --config ./bin/openvpn-lib/cert.ovpn --dev ovpntun0 --up ./bin/openvpn-  lib/update-resolv.conf --down ./bin/openvpn-lib/update-resolv.conf --script-security 2

expect "Enter Auth Username:"

send "myuser\n"

expect "Enter Auth Password:"

send "mypass\n"

interact
```

WHen I try to run it the scriptit reports the following error:

```
vpn_expect.sh: line 4: spawn: command not found
couldn't read file "Enter Auth Username:": no such file or directory
vpn_expect.sh: line 8: send: command not found
couldn't read file "Enter Auth Password:": no such file or directory
vpn_expect.sh: line 12: send: command not found
vpn_expect.sh: line 14: interact: command not found
vfbsilva@rohan ~ $
```

Comment: Add `interact` as the last line of the script.

Comment: the 3rd line should be `spawn openvpn ...` -- otherwise Expect cannot control the process.

Comment: did update the script but no luck

Comment: Dont start the script by saying `sh vpn_expect.sh` or similar. Either make the file executable (`chmod +x vpn_expect.sh`) then run it with `./vpn_expect.sh`, or run it with `expect vpn_expect.sh`.

Comment: @meuh comment did make the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expect scripts must be run with expect as

```
expect <script_name>
```

Running them as shell scripts with

```
sh <script_name>
```

Was the cause of the problem.